# Error on PdfReader.Open()

Tags: c#, pdf, windows, pdfsharp

I am using a windows application C# and I have this error appearing on my PdfReader.Open line here is the screenshot of the error

[image]

This is my code

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            CVNumber = row["CVNumber"].ToString();

            string sPath = sGlobalFolderName + "\\" + CVNumber + "_OR.pdf";
            try
            {
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(sPath))
                {
                    //PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
                    files.Add(PdfReader.Open(sPath));
                }

            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Error triggers in `files.Add(PdfReader.Open(sPath));` line.

I hope you can help me on this one. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How is the pdf file created? Can you open pdf file with Acrobat or other pdf reader?

Comment: @JacobSeleznev On my report viewer, i am exporting it to a pdf file.

Comment: Perhaps, PDF file is incorrect. Try finding answer on [forums](http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1146)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, it is an assertion.

Assertions do not show when you use a RELEASE build. Press `Ignore` when using the DEBUG build.

"Not implemented" is a bad sign. The file may or may not be read.

The latest version is PDFsharp 1.50 beta, available as a NuGet package. This version may work with PDF files the older versions cannot read.

If the problem persists, submit the PDF file to the PDFsharp team for examination.